# Best Fetching Practices in Hibernate Mapping (Many-To-One)

Tags: java, hibernate

I am having trouble with many-to-one mapping using hibernate. I have two tables, Table A and Table B. I mapped Many-to-One Relationship between these tables. Both tables can be use together as well as separately.

The representation of tables in terms of classes in Java like:

```
class A{ 
 private B b; 
 private Integer val1; 
 private Integer val2; 
 private Integer val3; 
}

class B{
 private Integer val1;
 private Integer val2;
 private Integer val3;
}
```

The problem is whenever I try to retrieve/fetch records from table A, hibernate also fetch records from Table B all the time which I do not want. It causing performance issues. Is their any way to deal with this situation?

Please guide me with an appropriate answer.

Answer (score 2):

```
@ManyToOne(lazy = true)
private B b;
```

Is all you need. Read the [hibernate documentation](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/reference/en-US/html_single/#performance-fetching-lazy) for more details.

Comment: +1 Just a side note: If you intend on using lazy fetching for *collections*, you should take a look at [Fetching Strategies](https://community.jboss.org/wiki/AShortPrimerOnFetchingStrategies) and determine which strategy best suits your needs.

Comment: I am not using Annotation... I put lazy=true in the hbm but its not accepting true value.

Comment: http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/reference/en-US/html_single/#d0e7761: scroll a bit down, and read all the properties you can set and their documentation. lazy="proxy" is what you want, and is also the default.

Answer (score 0):

Your requirement fits into `Lazy Initialization`. For achieving it, you can add either annotation or while retrieving data you can use hibernate session's `get` method.

In your case you can write like :

```
Session session = SessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
A aObject= (A) session.get(A.class, A_ID);
```

As stated in this https://community.jboss.org/wiki/AShortPrimerOnFetchingStrategies?_sscc=t link :

Hibernate3 loads a single entity instance if you retrieve it by identifier through get() or load(). All collections mapped for this entity, and all associated entities, be it through to-many or to-one associations, are not loaded.